# Adding NSDateComponents in a for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

Im trying to write a method that will run a for loop checking if a date is before today, and if it is, it needs to be incremented by a NSDateComponent

**Method to check if the date is before today:**

```
- (BOOL) isDatePassedToday:(NSDate *)recurringDate
{
    if ([recurringDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

**The Logic of how I need my for loop to work:**

```
-(NSDate *)calculateRecurringReminder:(NSDate *)startDate using:(NSDateComponents*)doItAgainComponents
{
    NSDate *recurringDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

    recurringDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:doItAgainComponents toDate:recurringDate options:0];

    // The loop to add components
    for ([self isDatePassedToday:recurringDate]; [self isDatePassedToday:recurringDate] == YES; doItAgainComponents)
    {

        recurringDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:doItAgainComponents toDate:recurringDate options:0];

    }

    return recurringDate;
}
```

Comment: so what you expect from us?

Comment: So what's your expected behaviour for the loop and what does it actually do?

Comment: I just want the loop to continually add the doItAgainComponents to the recurringDate until it is passed today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
-(NSDate *)calculateRecurringReminder:(NSDate *)startDate using:(NSDateComponents*)doItAgainComponents {
    NSDate *recurringDate = startDate;

    while (![self isDatePassedToday:recurringDate]) {
        recurringDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:doItAgainComponents toDate:recurringDate options:0];
    }

    return recurringDate;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, while this seems to be exactly what I need, it locks up my UI and doesn't seem to complete even on small calculations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps it is going in an infinite loop. Run this in the debugger and see why. Perhaps `recurringDate` isn't being incremented as expected or `isDatePassedToday` never returns `YES`.

Comment: Sorry, Im not thinking straight, and yes you are right it is going into a infinite loop. I think I know the problem, but my original question was answered, so thank you very much.